# How to change the suffix of my contact to a UK style?

Tags: contacts

How to change the suffix of my contact with a UK style?

Comment: Welcome to SE!  Could you provide an example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: I'm intrigued to know what you mean by "UK style". Name suffixes are not used as in US. Some people have honours or qualifications after their name (though most would not normally put Bsc, MA etc down), but they wouldn't work from a drop down list is that people can have quite a collection (the sort of person who wants to use them is the sort who accumulates a lot) and you would have to have an option for each possible combination that would be unworkable. The only situation where I can see where it might be desirable is where you have a qualification related members (eg a professional body).

Answer (score 2):

Are you referring to the suffixes drop down, Jr. Sn etc? if so…

You have full control of the list of suffixes:

*From the CiviCRM menu* –

**Administer > Customize Data and Screens > Dropdown Options > Individual Suffixes**

`/civicrm/admin/options/individual_suffix?reset=1`

From here, you can add, update and edit any of the options.